# Equilibrium distribution of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Can anyone please tell me or help me with this question shown below?

A drunken chess grandmaster dials a long string of digits on a standard telephone keypad (laid out as shown below). It takes more than alcohol to make a grandmaster forget the rules of chess, so each digit he dials is a knight's move away from the previous one (e.g. 4 can be followed by 3, 9, or 0). The choices are made at random, independently of previous ones, with all available knight's moves being equally likely to be chosen for each digit.

Find the equilibrium distribution of this Markov chain. (Hint: it helps to use the symmetry, e.g. 1 and 3 must have the same equilibrium probability.)

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
  0
```

I seem not to understand the question at all. Unlike finding other equilibrium distribution of a Markov Chain question where it is shown as a transition matrix with state space given, could anyone please help on trying to "read" and "identify" this question?

Your helps would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are of course shortcuts, and this problem is simple if you know the right shortcut, but this problem is still amenable to the standard techniques.  There are ten states, and the transition matrix is easily computed from the information given.  Write down the transition matrix and someone may take you on to the next steps.

Comment: If there are 10 states, does that mean that this should be a transition matrix of 10 x 10?

Comment: Yes. The transition matrix records the probability of going from one state to the next, and there are ten states you can start at and ten that you can end up in o you need a 10x10 matrix.

Comment: One question that comes up in writing the transition matrix is: what happens if he presses 5 first? Does he keep on pressing 5 forever or does he possibly press some other number as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the transition matrix looks like this (1 is the first entry and 0 is the last in each row/column). I have assumed that if the grand master presses $5$ first, we will randomly pick the next digit uniformly.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10}\\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Row 5 does not seem to sum to 1.  (I know this is because there is no knight's move from 5, but it raises an issue with the question)

Comment: Good point @Henry. We should just define some arbitrary transitions out of state 5 and never have transitions into state 5 (except from maybe state 5).

Comment: I have made the edit.

Comment: Why? Wouldn't the problem itself make 5 an absorbing state that you never can get into or out of? That just makes it dependent on initial conditions...

Comment: I agree that the question is whether 5 should be absorbing or not. As long as 5 isn't absorbing, then 5 will have 0 probability in the equilibrium distribution no matter how we pick what happens if 5 is pushed first. I have chosen to make 5 non-absorbing since then the equilibrium will not depend on initial conditions.

Comment: Why the probabilities from $5$ to other states are all $\dfrac{1}{10}$？ Isn't is should be $0$?